# PPTP VPN to Windows Server 2012: Can connect from some and some can't on the same network

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

Im having some odd issues with a PPTP VPN connection that has worked pretty much since forever. Server is a Windows Server 2012 R2.

These examples are all from clients on the same network (except on the 3G network) to a Windows Server 2012 R2 acting as a PPTP server

From a wired Windows 7 PC, I can connect perfectly.

From a Android device over wireless, I cannot connect

From the same Android device over 3G, I can connect perfectly.

From a wireless Windows 8.1 wired, I cannot connect

From that same Windows 8.1 laptop wired, I cannot connect

From a wired Synoglogy NAS, I cannot connect

From initial standpoint, it would seem that my firewall (pfSense) is BLOCKING OUTGOING connections which is very odd as most firewall do not block outgoing connections. That wouldnt explain though why my wired Windows 7 PC can connect.

It seems that over at the server side, the network configuration is correct. The client side seems to be what is lacking.

Any tips on where to look in pfSense?

Comment: pull your services and look the startup type.

Comment: On? Client? Server?

Comment: yes on client  .

Comment: And I look for what? I don't see any VPN, PPTP, etc. related service there.

Comment: Too Little information on where to even start looking.